# Built-in typedefs for chrono stuff?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, c++-chrono

Does C++ (>= 14) provide any built-in convenience typedefs for `time_point` and clock types?

The fully qualified names are pretty long, and sometimes I can't just use `auto` (like, for example, if I need to use chrono types as template parameters). There are easy ways to shorten them already, e.g.:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main () {

    {
        // fully qualified names are intense:
        vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>> times;
        times.push_back(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    }

    {
        // but this is straightforward:
        using namespace std::chrono;
        vector<time_point<steady_clock>> times;
        times.push_back(steady_clock::now());
    }

    {
        // so is this, which is basically what i currently do:
        using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
        using time = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;
        vector<time> times;
        times.push_back(clock::now());        
    }

}
```

So I already have a solution for shortening names that I use; **I'm just wondering if there's already some typedefs defined in the std libraries, or if I should just keep defining them myself as above.** Mostly just curious.

PS Another doozy is:

```
auto usecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endtime - starttime).count();
```

Comment: You can shorten the last option a littbe bit by using `using time = clock::time_point;`. (Works for any [*Clock*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Clock)) I'm pretty sure there's no way of shortening `std::chrono::steady_clock` though by means other than `using namespace ...;` or `namespace identifier = ...;`; The standard library seems to emphasize making things unambiguous.

Comment: @fabian Oh cool; hey I'll take what I can get, thanks!

Comment: Why is typing a bit more now such a big issue? Anyone reading your code later (including your future self) is better of with the standard (fully qualified) names then some alias that is unique to each project and depends on the preferences of a specific developer. Use auto and (inline) functions where you can fully qualified anywhere else. (Say what you mean and mean what you say)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I appreciate your input. This question is about what's defined in standard headers, not about style. It's a language specification question. If you'd like, imagine the entire thing is prefaced with "not that I'd *ever* use them" or something; but the question would still stand. :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer [OT] Now, on the topic of style; sure; although there is also a strong argument for, say, `using performance_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock; using performance_timestamp = performance_clock::time_point;` being a semantic *improvement*. Also, those using statements *are* part of saying what you mean, if you look at them like "I want to use this type as a performance clock."

Comment: And yes ofcourse I agree with you that std::chrono is a bit verbose.  And yes "using Thanks, I am not trying to be mean by any account :) And yes using `my_clock_t  = std::chrono::steady_clock` has entered my code a few times too :) 
The other thing I do is to write wrapper classes that model what I want to do and keep the time datatypes internal.  With C++20 at least you could make some concepts to make your code cleaner for templates. There is still the possiblity I haven't quite understood your question either :)

Comment: @JasonC Abstractions like that are fine, because they indeed improve semantics. What I try to say is don't abbreviate for abbreviatons sake :) So no argument from me here.

Comment: @fabian's answer is what I was going to say as well.  Additionally, when you migrate to C++20, some additional convenience type aliases are introduced.  For example to get `time_point`s based on `system_clock` of various precisions.  I often use _local_ using directives myself.

Comment: @fabian It's pretty clear that the answer is "nope; just the clock's `::time_point` type". If you want some free internet points you're welcome to stick that up as an answer. Otherwise, I guess this question will just... fade away...   Thanks all!